# An alternative to "pray" without a religious connotation

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

When I write, I try my best to leave religion and words that carry some divine connotation out of it. I recently stumbled upon the phrase in one of my texts:

> [...] but **pray** it never happens.

I am wondering how to rewrite it, removing the connection with deities but keeping the same *effect/meaning*. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use *hope*

Comment: I could, but it just doesn't carry the same strength/weight/intensity as pray... I was *hoping* for a better word. *(pun intended)*

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't carry the same strength? I don't see any difference in strength.  Of course you could say, *I was hoping like hell* but that might be back to having religious undertones, eh?

Comment: You better *hope against hope* it never happens. *fervently hope*, *have confidence*

Comment: Are you seeking the intervention of some force to bring about your preference? If not, isn't it just *hope, wish, yearn, worry, fret, desire* or some other affect term rather than an influence term?

Comment: You might quantify the probability of an unwanted event rather than invoke luck or the divine: "*But the likelihood of that happening is less than 1 in 370,000*"

Comment: Any other word, esp., one without a religious connotation, cannot mean 'pray' as in the given context. In the OP's sentence, the word *pray* implies appealing to the almighty God, and nothing less.

Comment: @Nicole how is my question a duplicate if I asked it BEFORE the other one? If the moderation could remove the duplicated marking off of this I would certainly appreciate it.

Comment: I agree, and am voting to reopen. C'mon, people, do the math. September '14 came before December '14.

Comment: OP, do you have any reason for doing this? What's wrong with religiously praying?

Comment: Closely related: [Non-religious equivalent expression for “Pray for Country X” after a disaster](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214822/non-religious-equivalent-expression-for-pray-for-country-x-after-a-disaster)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably your best word is hope:

> [Hope](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Hope): to wish for something with expectation of its fulfillment; the feeling that what is wanted can be had or that events will turn out well.

You can also wish well for someone:

> [Wish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wish): A desire, longing, or strong inclination for a specific thing.

From the Free Dictionary.

Comment: Not going to beat hope/wish here.

Comment: I guess it will have to do, *hope* is kind of a boring word though... Sometimes the english language can be disappointing...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context you could swap it around and find a negative phrase instead: "I *dread* the day it happens", "the prospect *terrifies* me", or similar. It might be easier to find intense negative words than positive ones.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not actually a response to your question, I'd suggest that you are being excessively deity-phobic. "Pray" has, in our secular society, taken on a non-religious meaning as well as its original.

> : to speak to God especially in order to give thanks or to ask for
>   something
>
> : to hope or wish very much for something to happen
>
> : to seriously ask (someone) to do something

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pray

It's hard to see even a tinge of religious sentiment in a question like, "And what, pray tell, do you think you're doing?"

In trying to avoid "pray" in your original example, you make your sentence more complex and less pithy. If the phrase were "but pray to God that it never happens", I'd just suggest leaving out "to God", but the phrase as it stands has no religious connotation that I can detect.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply, 
  "May it never happen."

This implies the entreaty to someone or something greater than ourselves without raising the question of *to whom* the entreaty is addressed.

Answer (score -2):

In the sense that a *prayer* is a begging request ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pray)),

> 1) to offer devout petition, praise, thanks, etc., to (God or an object of worship)
>   4) to make earnest petition to (a person)
>   5) to make petition or entreaty for; crave

you could use **plead** ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plead)):

> 1) to appeal or entreat earnestly

Comment: You better *plead* it never happens??  I don't think it quite fits.

Comment: -1 Plead with whom?